# ZipRuby - Zipping files with duplicate names (clean code)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, coding-style, zip

I have altered my code to prevent an error when zipping a number of files that have the same file name. I want to change it so that duplicate file names are incremented.

For example if you had three files called file.txt, then I want them to be `file.txt`, `file_2.txt` and `file_3.txt`

```
def zip(file_name)
  files_added = []
  ZipRuby::Archive.open(file_name, ZipRuby::CREATE) do |archive|
    file_associations.sort_by { |fa| fa.created_at }.each do |fa|
      attachment_file_name = fa.attachment_file_name
      binding.pry

      if files_added.include?(attachment_file_name)
        n = 2
        ext = File.extname(attachment_file_name)
        base = File.basename(attachment_file_name, ext)
        new_name = "#{base}_#{n}#{ext}"
        while files_added.include? new_name
          n += 1
          new_name = "#{base}_#{n}#{ext}"
        end
        attachment_file_name = new_name
      end

      archive.add_buffer(attachment_file_name, fa.attachment.read)
      files_added << attachment_file_name
    end
  end
end
```

The code above works but I am new to Ruby/Rails and it doesn't feel very Rubyist. Can anyone give any pointers for a refactor.